# highcharts pie drilldown not working in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, highcharts, meteor

currently i am using meteorjs 0.9.2 and highcharts 4.0.4

but highcharts pie drilldown not worked, it shows an pie view but clicking event on that pie not worked so i cant get drilldown on pie

i think there is some problems in highcharts work with meteorjs, formatter is not working

all other except events that i tested working fine

here i paste my code in meteorjs, this code working perfectly in html + javascript

```
Template.highcharts.rendered = function() {

var A = [{"name":"cited","drilldown":"DsbsswZFzacLnTPvZ","y":303},{"name":"citing","drilldown":"zKgitWhpv5bZE2wjr","y":218}];
var B = [{"name":"A61K","id":"czZdakWbYzBaq8hu3","data":[["BEIERSDORF AG",1036],["OREAL",583]]},{"name":"A61F","id":"37zqcAeDWCks5xAtL","data":[["BEIERSDORF AG",61],["MINNESOTA MINING & MFG",22]]},{"name":"cited","id":"DsbsswZFzacLnTPvZ","data":[{"name":"A61K","y":1367,"drilldown":"czZdakWbYzBaq8hu3"},{"name":"A61F","y":487,"drilldown":"37zqcAeDWCks5xAtL"}]},{"name":"A61K","id":"HPgny8W554ySyMRpE","data":[["BEIERSDORF AG",587],["OREAL",450]]},{"name":"A61F","id":"AnvkHrMJC5r5rgGeY","data":[["BEIERSDORF AG",64],["KIMBERLY CLARK CO",25]]},{"name":"citing","id":"zKgitWhpv5bZE2wjr","data":[{"name":"A61K","y":959,"drilldown":"HPgny8W554ySyMRpE"},{"name":"A61F","y":296,"drilldown":"AnvkHrMJC5r5rgGeY"}]}];

            $("#highcharts").highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: "pie"
                },

                title: {text: "Citation Analysis"},
                subtitle: {text: "Client: Linto Cheeran"},


                drilldown: {
                    series: B
                },
                series: [{
                    data: A, name: "root",
                }],

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {enabled: true},
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

there is no error shows in console

pls help me

how i do pie drilldown in highchart with meteorjs ?

Comment: Dimple drilldown with your data works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/y9czkn8n/ - maybe you don't have `drilldown.js` plugin?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oLxp4vz3/ that i already tested outside meteor, but there is some problems in meteorjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highchart packages available in [atmospherejs](http://atmospherejs.com/) doesn't have drilldown module, So you have to add drilldown.js seperately.

Comment: drilldown plugin not in atmosphere package atmospherejs.com/mrt/highcharts, that's the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Everything works like a charm with meteor.

You can test it on [meteorpad.com](http://meteorpad.com/pad/G7eSQW5mFfhE4M2uA)

Comment: drilldown plugin not in atmosphere package https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/highcharts, that's the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

As of now even MaazAli's popular highcharts package on atmosphere doesn't include it. I made a new package that includes MaazAli's popular highcharts package on atmosphere to also have the **drilldown module**.

`meteor add clarencel:highcharts`

See: https://atmospherejs.com/clarencel/highcharts-drilldown